# I have a ruby array of filepaths (./dir2/chico.html) and I can't seem to get it to sort correctly

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, filepath

So I have my array: (This isn't the exact order of the elements, just an example)

```
myArray = {./dir2/chico.html, ./dir2/chico.rb, ./dir1/c.js, ./dir1/g.txt, ./dir1/d.css}
```

When I do a sort using...

```
myArray.sort
```

The results come out unsorted...

```
./dir2/chico.html
./dir2/chico.rb
./dir1/c.js
./dir1/g.txt
./dir1/d.css
```

What I want is for all the dir1 files to come before dir2. And d.css should come before g.txt. Why isn't it sorting?

Comment: That's an invalid assignment in Ruby, and those aren't strings within the curly braces, and hashes are encapsulated in curly braces, not arrays. `myArray = ['./dir2/chico.html', './dir2/chico.rb', './dir1/c.js', './dir1/g.txt', './dir1/d.css']; myArray.sort => ["./dir1/c.js", "./dir1/d.css", "./dir1/g.txt", "./dir2/chico.html", "./dir2/chico.rb"]`

So the sorting works fine.

Answer (score 0):

from irb.

```
irb(main):001:0> ary = ["./dir2/chico.html", "./dir2/chico.rb", "./dir1/c.js",   "./dir1/g.txt", "./dir1/d.css"]
=> ["./dir2/chico.html", "./dir2/chico.rb", "./dir1/c.js", "./dir1/g.txt", "./dir1/d.css"]
irb(main):002:0> puts ary
./dir2/chico.html
./dir2/chico.rb
./dir1/c.js
./dir1/g.txt
./dir1/d.css
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> puts ary.sort
./dir1/c.js
./dir1/d.css
./dir1/g.txt
./dir2/chico.html
./dir2/chico.rb
=> nil
```

Each element in the array needs to be surrounded by " " or ' '.
The syntax for an array is [ ], hashes are { }

Answer (score 0):

Building off what "user2891803" said. You need to construct your array differently. You have initialized a hash with the name of "myArray" giving you a false sense of what type of container your using. Also when coding, this goes for all languages, try an name your variables as descriptive, concise, and precise as possible; don't be afraid to make long variable names. Underscores work wonders in readability!

```
myArray = ['./dir2/chico.html', './dir2/chico.rb', './dir1/c.js', './dir1/g.txt', './dir1/d.css']
puts myArray.sort
```

This should work for what you are trying to do. 
    Happy ruby!